# Выборка данных с условием

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT   
ic.Name as 'Класс страхование',
MIN(ip.Name) as 'Страховой продукт', 
SUM(case when dea.DealState in ('Signed', 'Cancelled','Deleted') then 1 else 0 end) Policies,
SUM(case when dea.DealState in ('Signed', 'Cancelled') then 1 else 0 end) SignedPolicies
From
Deals dea
inner join Products pr   ON dea.ID = pr.DealID
inner join InsuranceProducts  ip ON pr.InsuranceProductCode = ip.Code
inner join InsuranceSubproducts isub  ON ip.Code = isub.[InsuranceProduct] and ip.Code != 100 and ip.Code != 89
inner join InsSubproductsClasses ins ON ins.[SubproductCode] = isub.Code
inner join InsuranceClasses ic   ON ins.[ClassCode] = ic.Code 
Group By    ic.Name, ip.Name
```

Запрос выводить такой результат:

```
| Класс страхование | Страховой продукт | Policies | SignedPolicies |
+-------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+
| НС                | Product 2         | 8        | 0              |
| ОГПО              | Имущество         | 40       | 3              |
| Авто              | Двойная защита    | 16       | 0              |
| Добровольное      | НС (Граница)      | 154      | 154            |
```

Как мне выбрать только заключенные договора (то есть SignedPolicies)?
Ожидаю такой результат:

```
 | Класс страхование | Страховой продукт | Policies | SignedPolicies |
 +-------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+
 | ОГПО              | Имущество         | 40       | 3              |
 | Добровольное      | НС (Граница)      | 154      | 154            |
```

Comment: Оберните ваш запрос в еще один `select` или СTE и добавьте условие `where SignedPolicies > 0`

Comment: @null, можете привести пример

Comment: оформил пример как ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать конструкцию [HAVING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms180199%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) для фильтрации результатов группировки:

```
...
Group By ic.Name, ip.Name
HAVING SUM(case when dea.DealState in ('Signed', 'Cancelled') then 1 else 0 end)  > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;with cte as(
SELECT   
ic.Name as 'Класс страхование',
MIN(ip.Name) as 'Страховой продукт', 
SUM(case when dea.DealState in ('Signed', 'Cancelled','Deleted') then 1 else 0 end) Policies,
SUM(case when dea.DealState in ('Signed', 'Cancelled') then 1 else 0 end) SignedPolicies
From
Deals dea
inner join Products pr   ON dea.ID = pr.DealID
inner join InsuranceProducts  ip ON pr.InsuranceProductCode = ip.Code
inner join InsuranceSubproducts isub  ON ip.Code = isub.[InsuranceProduct] and ip.Code != 100 and ip.Code != 89
inner join InsSubproductsClasses ins ON ins.[SubproductCode] = isub.Code
inner join InsuranceClasses ic   ON ins.[ClassCode] = ic.Code 
Group By    ic.Name, ip.Name
)
select *
from cte
where SignedPolicies > 0
```